# How to compile Java 7-compatible code under JDK 9 (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7, java-9

I've updated to ***JDK 9***, but some users of my apps report that application does not start up (*they have Java 7*).

How can I compile my code the way it will be compatible with Java 7?
I am using Eclipse.

EDIT : **It's not a duplicate**. The question you are referring to does NOT answer my question. I can edit environments, but I don't think that using `JDK 9.0.1` as `JDK 1.7` would actually compile under `1.7`.

Comment: Maybe it is. But I've searched in google; then searched before I typed in question title; and another time when I actually did type it. 
And I didn't see this question there.

Comment: Actually it does answer your question, if you read about the Java compliance level.  You can have Java 9 installed but compile the code to be compliant under java 7.